# Сумма nullable чисел в Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, lambda

Для редукции чисел используется лямбда

```
{ a : Int, b: Int -> a + b }
```

Но мне попался код, что ожидает лямбду с nullable числами

```
(Int?, Int?) -> Int?
```

И приходится писать как-то так

```
{ a : Int?, b : Int? -> a!! + b!! }
{ a : Int?, b : Int? -> a?.plus(b!!) }
```

но использование `!!` ведь нежелательно, так как не безопасно все же для `null` с точки зрения Kotlin, а без него приходится писать еще хуже

```
{ a : Int?, b : Int? -> b?.let { a?.plus(b) ?: b } ?: a ?: 0 }
```

или что б передать логику

```
{ a : Int?, b : Int? -> when {
    a == null && b == null -> 0
    a == null -> b
    b == null -> a
    else -> a + b
}}
```

Воспрос в том, как сделать подобную лямбду лаконичной, красивой и безопасной?

Comment: Пришел к

    { a : Int?, b : Int? -> (a ?: 0) + (b ?: 0)  }

Скорее всего лучше не сделать уже

Comment: да, хорошее решение

Comment: @Feodott стоит написать решение в ответе (вместо комментария) и закрыть данный вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пришел к

```
{ a : Int?, b : Int? -> (a ?: 0) + (b ?: 0) }
```

Скорее всего лучше не сделать уже